# Django query annotate and agregate

Tags: django

How can I write a query like this in Django?

```
  select sum(kolvo), reason
  from(
  select count(reason) kolvo, reason
  from contacts group by reason) group by reason
```

Comment: What is the difference between just `SELECT count(reason) kolvo, reason FROM contacts GROUP BY reason`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks semantically equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT count(reason) AS kolvo,
       reason
FROM contacts
GROUP BY reason
```

So without the outer query.

You can make such query in Django's ORM with:

```py
Contacts.objects.values('reason').annotate(
    kolvo=Count('id')
).order_by('reason')
```

This will then return a `QuerySet` that wraps dictionaries, like:

```
< QuerySet [
    { 'reason': 'some reason', 'kolvo': 13 },
    { 'reason': 'some other reason', 'kolvo': 2 },
] >
```